# Python chroot type behavior cross platform

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to simulate chroot type behaviour for python. [`os.chroot`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chroot) works only with Unix, as per the documentation. I need it for Windows as well. One way I have tried to implement it is by defining a root path and a method `abs_path` which converts a given path relative to the root. Here is the snippet of `abs_path` after removing some irrelevant code. `self.wd.get()` fetches the Current Working Directory.

```
def abs_path(self, rel_path):
        """
        Converts relative path to absolute path
        Taking care of the virtual root
        """
        if rel_path == '':
            return os.path.abspath(os.path.join(self.root, self.wd.get()))
        if rel_path[0] == '/':
            ret = os.path.join(self.root, rel_path)
        else:
            ret = os.path.join(self.root, self.wd.get(), rel_path)

        ret = os.path.abspath(ret)
        if ret.find(self.root) == 0:
            return ret
        return self.root
```

This seems to work fine under Linux and I believe it should work well with Windows as well. The main thing I am worried about is `if ret.find(self.root) == 0:`, which I am using to check for cases where the `ret` evaluates to a path higher than the root. eg. if `root=/home/user/`, then `rel_path=/abc/../../` should evaluate to an absolute path `/home/user/`. What should be the better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `chroot()` in unix is doing that at the process level, which every forked process can't escape. Your method hides other pathes, but if an exploiter achieves to exploit your code so it executes malicious code and will have access to your whole filesystem.

A little search on google lead to those answers:

- [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686578/fork-chroot-equivalent-for-windows-server-application)
- [on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/161507/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-to-chroot), and
- [on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/356408/can-i-chroot-to-a-linux-environment-from-windows)

as well as a few applications that does it:

- http://blog.airesoft.co.uk/2012/01/chroot-ing-in-windows-as-easy-as-a-b-c/
- http://www.airesoft.co.uk/chroot

you may achieve that using the windows API [as suggested by this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273939/python-subprocess-popen-as-different-user-on-windows).

And finally, you can make your own abstraction to run a subprocess in a chrooted environment using `chroot` on unix systems, and `runas` on windows! All that, without having to create a path faker but with a better security.

Comment: ...as a complement, does not overestimate `chroot`. Is is [not really a security feature](http://securityblog.redhat.com/2013/03/27/is-chroot-a-security-feature/).

Comment: indeed, I can only support and vote for your comment. The OP asked about a portable `chroot`-like feature, and I suggested him a way to make an abstraction over that. His solution is a lot less secure than using a real `chroot`, as well as using a real `chroot` is a lot less secure than using a virtualized environment (and a lot more security features one can add to protect his system).